# Web scraping of coursera website yields different results in every run

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-3.7

So, I'm trying to scrape some MOOC sites for a project of mine and started with Coursera. So, the first thing I did was to scrape the first page of 'coursera.org/courses'. That worked. But when I tried iterating from the first to the tenth page, many times instead of scraping the corresponding page it would scrape the first one.

I later tried to scrape any one of the pages except for the first for about four times. More often than not, in at least one of the four runs the page scraped would actually be the first not the one I wanted.

Any solutions?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

def get_site_file(url):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Safari()
        driver.implicitly_wait(80)
        driver.get(url)
        bs=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
        driver.close()
        return bs;
    except HTTPError as e:
        print("Site not found"+e)

def scrape_site(url):
    try:
        pgcn=get_site_file(url)
    except:
        print("Could not parse")
    try:
        discovered_courses=pgcn.find("ul",{'class':'ais-InfiniteHits-list'})
    except:
        print("Did not find something specific to the tag")
    if(pgcn==None):
        print("Page not found")
    else:
        courses=pgcn.find("ul",{'class':'ais-InfiniteHits-list'})
        for course in courses:
            try:
                course_title = course.h2.get_text()
                course_rating = course.find('span',{'class': 'ratings-text'}).\
                get_text()
                print(f"Course Title: \t {course_title}")
                print(f"Course Rating: \t {course_rating}")
                print('\n'+('|')+('<'*3)+('-'*7)+' New Course ' +('-'*7)+('>'*3)+('|')+'\n')
            except:
                print("Something went wronf when printing the courses")

for i in range(4):
    scrape_site("https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=&indices%5Bprod_all_products_term_optimization_test%5D%5Bpage%5D="+str(i+1)+"&indices%5Bprod_all_products_term_optimization_test%5D%5Bconfigure%5D%5BclickAnalytics%5D=true&indices%5Bprod_all_products_term_optimization_test%5D%5Bconfigure%5D%5BhitsPerPage%5D=10&configure%5BclickAnalytics%5D=true")
    print("\n\n")
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Just updated post with code

Answer (score 0):

One of you problems is that you are making HTTP GET requests when the website is expecting HTTP POST requests.

You can simulate click events with ActionChains to make the POST requests.

Another problem was trying to iterate through an "ul" element, you need to use find_all() on the "li" elements.

You can use something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


def find_courses(source):
    pgcn = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
    if pgcn is None:
        print("Page not found")
    else:
        courses = pgcn.find_all("li", {'class': 'ais-InfiniteHits-item'})
        for course in courses:
            try:
                course_title = course.h2.get_text()
                course_rating = course.find('span', {'class': 'ratings-text'}). \
                    get_text()
                print(f"Course Title: \t {course_title}")
                print(f"Course Rating: \t {course_rating}")
                print('\n' + '|' + ('<' * 3) + ('-' * 7) + ' New Course ' + ('-' * 7) + ('>' * 3) + '|' + '\n')
            except:
                print("Something went wrong when printing the courses")

url = "https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=&indices%5Bprod_all_products_term_optimization_test%5D%5Bpage%5D=1&indices%5Bprod_all_products_term_optimization_test%5D%5Bconfigure%5D%5BclickAnalytics%5D=true&indices%5Bprod_all_products_term_optimization_test%5D%5Bconfigure%5D%5BhitsPerPage%5D=10&configure%5BclickAnalytics%5D=true"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(80)
for i in range(3):
    element = driver.find_element_by_id('pagination_right_arrow_button')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
    find_courses(driver.page_source)
    ActionChains(driver).click().perform()
    driver.implicitly_wait(80)
driver.quit()
```

Outputs:

```
Course Title:    Machine Learning
Course Rating:   4.9

|<<<------- New Course ------->>>|

...
Course Title:    Introduction to Data Science in Python
Course Rating:   4.5

|<<<------- New Course ------->>>|
```